# You uploaded an APK or You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver withintentfilter

Tags: react-native, store, playback

**I'm having an issue when i'm uploading app bundle to the play console that You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. but my manifest file includes the property android:exported="true".** [i.stack.imgur.com/Ux97W.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux97W.png)

here is my manifest file.

```
    <application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:resizeableActivity="false">
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
          android:host="af8c-110-235-232-163.ngrok.io"
          android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

       <activity
          android:exported="true"
          android:name="com.zoontek.rnbootsplash.RNBootSplashActivity"
          android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
          android:launchMode="singleTask">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>

  <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                android:value="false"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:exported="true" android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />
</application>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Can you please add any error logs that you are seeing?

Comment: when i upload app on play store hit me this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux97W.png

Comment: Please copy and paste the error into the body of your post

Comment: i have add please help me what i wrong.